# Index of div element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html:

```
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row"><input type="text" onchange="javascript:getIndex(this);" value="" /></div>
  <div class="row"><input type="text" onchange="javascript:getIndex(this);" value="" /></div>
  <div class="row"><input type="text" onchange="javascript:getIndex(this);" value="" /></div>
</div>
```

my function:

```
function getIndex(elem) {
    var $i = $(elem).parent().parent();
    alert($i.index($(elem).parent()));
}
```

I keep getting -1 telling me its not found... I looked into it and tried to spit out the value within the obj parent.
alert($(elem).parent().html());  this returns me the  tag with the default value that was changed...but if i alert $(obj).val() its totally different. So I am thinking that maybe the reason I keep getting a -1.

Has anyone experience this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getIndex(elem) {
    var $t = $(elem);
    alert($t.parent().index());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
function getIndex(elem) {
    var $i = $(elem).parent();
    alert($i.index());
}
```